# Сan there be different "input" values in one "samplers" (glTF, glb)

Tags: gltf

I'm trying to understand the format of glTF, tell me please

Сan there be different "input" values in one "samplers". Or is this redundant information?

```
    "samplers":[
{"input":7,"interpolation":"LINEAR","output":8},
{"input":7,"interpolation":"LINEAR","output":9},
{"input":7,"interpolation":"LINEAR","output":10},
{"input":7,"interpolation":"LINEAR","output":11},
{"input":7,"interpolation":"LINEAR","output":12},
{"input":7,"interpolation":"LINEAR","output":13}]}],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [glTF specification's section on animation](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md#animations) explains what these keywords mean. Each sampler contains:

- **input**: times for each keyframe in an animation channel
- **output**: values for some property at each keyframe in an animation channel
- **interpolation**: how values are computed between stored keyframes

The inputs are all the same because all of these tracks have keyframes at the same times. They reference a single binary accessor (`7`) to avoid storing those keyframe times repeatedly. Each track has different values, though, so those are stored in different accessors for each sampler.

Inputs do not have to be the same for different samplers, though, that just happens to be the case here.

Comment: Have you seen examples of files in which the "input" was different in one "sampler"?

Comment: Here's one: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/69968ab60ac2617bd2af21f4cc1f616de80da65b/2.0/BrainStem/glTF/BrainStem.gltf#L1472